# Can an istio service be for an arbitrary hostname?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

For in-mesh networking (no ingress or egress in my simple example), it seems like the common practice to have the "host" of a virtual service match an existing kubernetes service:

```
hosts:
- reviews.default.svc.cluster.local
```

But is this *required*? If I wanted to create a virtual service for an entirely different host name, is that possible? For example:

```
hosts:
- review-service.my-servicemesh
```

And then call the service at http://review-service.my-servicemesh instead of http://reviews (or http://reviews.default) ?

Or to ask this another way: can I have my namespace of istio (virtual) services be entirely decoupled from the namespace of kubernetes services/namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be acheived using istio [Service Entry](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=013699703217164175118:veyyqmfmpj4&q=https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjElff8p5nmAhXs6XMBHXeVCLcQFjAFegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0yjuqFqbiwP3M9p8LbEmrT). You can create something like this

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: review-servicemesh
spec:
  hosts:
  - "review-service.my-servicemesh"
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: STATIC [or even DNS]
  endpoints:
  - address: <your_endpoint_address>
```

Comment: That's useful for external-to-kubernetes, but I was asking more about within-kubernetes: do I have to use the "kubernetes name" of a kubernetes service, or can I use any name I want?

Comment: you have to use kubernetes name only, it is not possible to create service alias for services within the cluster.